# Chartjs disable legend click does not work when condition is not evaluated

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, chart.js

I am using chartjs and I have a case where I don't want to perform any action when a legend item is clicked. I managed to achieve this using the code below:

```
legend: {
    position: 'right',
    onClick: (e) => {
      if (!this.isFilterView)
        e.stopPropagation();
},
```

However when it is filter view I still want the legend items to work normally when clicked. The above code does not achieve this. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your own `legend.onClick` function overwrites the default function. Therefore stopping event propagation has no effect.

According to the code snippets in the section ["Custom On Click Actions"](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#custom-on-click-actions) from the Chart.js documentation, you have to explicitly invoke the default `onClick` function in order to obtain default behavior. Your code would have to be changed as follows:

```
var defaultLegendClickHandler = Chart.defaults.global.legend.onClick;
...
legend: {
  position: 'right',
  onClick: (event, legendItem) => {
    if (this.isFilterView) {
      defaultLegendClickHandler(event, legendItem);
    }
  },
```

I couldn't get this to work, though. As an alternative, you can toggle the hidden state of the datasets yourself depending on the value of `isFilterView`.

```
legend: {      
  onClick: (event, legendItem) => {
    if (this.isFilterView) {
      myChart.getDatasetMeta(legendItem.datasetIndex).hidden = !legendItem.hidden;
      myChart.update();
    }
  }
},
```

Please have a look at below runnable code snippet that illustrates how it works. The variable `isFilterView` can be toggled through a checkbox that appears top left of the canvas.

```js
var isFilterView = false;

var myChart = new Chart('chart', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'John Doe',
        data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        backgroundColor: 'red'
      },
      {
        label: 'Jane Clark',
        data: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
        backgroundColor: 'blue'
      },
      {
        label: 'Michael Smith',
        data: [3, 4, 2, 1, 5],
        backgroundColor: 'green'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {      
      onClick: (event, legendItem) => {
        if (isFilterView) {
          myChart.getDatasetMeta(legendItem.datasetIndex).hidden = !legendItem.hidden;
          myChart.update();
        }
      }
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          stepSize: 1
        }
      }],
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<input id="filterToggle" type="checkbox" onclick='isFilterView = !isFilterView;'>Filter View
<canvas id="chart" height="80"></canvas>
```